# Acumatica: How do I get an attachment file from SO Screen using Web API?

Tags: api, acumatica

I'd folow the example From I200 pdf for a stock item, but I dont' know how to download the file from an Sales Order. Does anybody has a clue?

```
IN202500Content stockItemSchema = context.IN202500GetSchema();
var commands = new Command[]
{
   new Value
   {
     Value = "AAMACHINE1",
     LinkedCommand = stockItemSchema.StockItemSummary.InventoryID
   },
   new Value
   {
     FieldName = "T2MCRO.jpg",
     LinkedCommand =
     stockItemSchema.StockItemSummary.ServiceCommands.Attachment
   }
};
var stockItemAttachment =
context.IN202500Export(commands, null, 1, false, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, in the "stockItemAttachment" variable you should have the content of the file "T2MCRO.jpg" in byte format.

The only thing you have left to do is to write it to your file system.
You can use the following command :

File.WriteAllBytes(Path, Convert.FromBase64String(stockItemAttachment[0][0]));